# WM_NCHITTEST and Detecting the Title bar of a Window

Tags: windows, mouse, autohotkey

I am relatively new to the world of programming. I've been using AutoHotkey a lot and came accross a code using WM_NCHITTEST. The code below: When the mouse cursor is above a window Title Bar, Right Click minimizes the window and Middle Click closes it. When the X coordinate of the mouse cursor is > 0, everything works fine (all windows and monitors to the **RIGHT** of the Main Display). When X < 0, nothing works (everything to the **LEFT** of the Main Display). Is someone able to explain this?

Specifically, the **"WM_NCHITTEST,, x | (y << 16)"**, I don't quite understand.

Link to the Original Code: [https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=76&t=63022&p=269207&hilit=titlebar+middle+click#p269207](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=76&t=63022&p=269207&hilit=titlebar%20middle%20click#p269207)

Link to Windows documentation of WM_NCHITTEST: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-nchittest

```
#If MouseIsOverTitlebar()
RButton::SendMessage 0x112, 0xF020
MButton::WinClose

MouseIsOverTitlebar() {
    static WM_NCHITTEST := 0x84, HTCAPTION := 2
    CoordMode Mouse, Screen
    MouseGetPos x, y, w
    if WinExist("ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd ahk_id " w)  ; Exclude taskbar.
        return false
    SendMessage WM_NCHITTEST,, x | (y << 16),, ahk_id %w%
    WinExist("ahk_id " w)  ; Set Last Found Window for convenience.
    return ErrorLevel = HTCAPTION
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SendMessage, Msg, wParam, lParam, Control, WinTitle
```

This is a send message command from AHK. See [SendMessage Tutorial](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/SendMessage.htm) and [SendMessage](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/PostMessage.htm).

For a [WM_NCHITTEST message](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-nchittest), use `0x84` for `Msg`. See [message list](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/SendMessageList.htm).

```
static WM_NCHITTEST := 0x84
SendMessage, WM_NCHITTEST, wParam, lParam, Control, WinTitle
```

Now the WM_NCHITTEST message require the cursor coordinate for `lParam` like this

> lParam
>
> The low-order word specifies the x-coordinate of the cursor. The
> coordinate is relative to the upper-left corner of the screen.
>
> The high-order word specifies the y-coordinate of the cursor. The
> coordinate is relative to the upper-left corner of the screen.

Basically, `x | (y << 16)` is a way to squeeze 2 variables in one as required. See [High-order word, low-order word](https://www.quickmacros.com/help/Other/IDP_HIWORD.html) and [Bitwise operations in C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C).

Now, instead of using `x` and `y` as integer directly, we need to take care of the negative value. Use signed 16-bit values (Short) instead.

```
SendMessage, WM_NCHITTEST,, (x & 0xFFFF) | ((y & 0xFFFF) << 16),, ahk_id %w%
```

Comment: To retrieve `x` and `y` from `lParam`, see [Get the coordinates of a WM_NCHITTEST message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471231/get-the-coordinates-of-a-wm-nchittest-message/6388667#6388667).